# how to calculate number of years in compound interest

Tags: finance

I'm trying to calculate **the number of years** in **compound interest**, but I find that the online formula can't get the answer I want. I don't know why. Does anyone know what the specific formula is? I know the calculator can done that, but I need to use formula for programming.

The formula I use is $n = \dfrac{\ln(FV / PV)}{\ln(1 + r)}$, but the result is $15.114$ something, but not as what the picture shows.

This is what suppose to be:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the interest in compounded half-yearly, the $r$ in your equation is $6.45\%/2$. This is how they arrive at their answer.

However, I think the question and model answer are a bit misleading. I'd usually say that the half-yearly interest is $(1+r)^{1/2}-1$, for an annual interest of $r$.

Comment: so how should I use formula to find the results?

Comment: Set $r = 6.45\%/2$. Then $N = \ln{(10000/4000)}/\ln{(1+ 6.45\%/2)}$

Comment: okokok,got it, thx